# Cant call a method in same java class

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I haven't wrote java in ages, and I know my question is really simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out the error.

I'm trying to find the smallest number in a array, using the below code. The algorithm is right, but i get an error when trying to use it in the last print statement

```
package runtime;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class app {


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public int findSmallElement(ArrayList<Integer> num)
{
    int smElement; 
    smElement= num.get(0);
    for(int i=0; i<num.size() ; i++)
        if(num.get(i) < smElement)
            smElement=num.get(i);
    return smElement;
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList<Object> num = new ArrayList<Object>();



    num.add(100);
    num.add(80);
    num.add(40);
    num.add(20);
    num.add(60);

    System.out.println("The size of the list is " +num.size());
    System.out.println(num.findSmallElement());

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call your method on an ArrayList variable/object, which does not have this method, when instead you want to call it on an instance of your own class. You should pass your array list into this method.

Another option is to make your method static and simply call it by itself, again passing in the arraylist.

```
//  add the static modifier
public static int findSmallElement(ArrayList<Integer> num)
```

and then call like:

```
// pass the ArrayList into your findSmallElement method call
int smallestElement = findSmallElement(num);
// display the result:
System.out.println("smallest element: " + smallestElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` **doesn't** have a `findSmallElement` method. Make your method `static` and call it passing in `num` like

```
System.out.println(findSmallElement(num));
```

**and**

```
public static int findSmallElement(ArrayList<Integer> num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making your method a static, like all the others stated above, you can create an object and call it through that, which I think is more convenient

```
App app = new App();
int smallestElement = app.findSmallElement(sum);
System.out.println("smallest element: " + smallestElement);
```

I'm not quite sure, but I think this works.

Answer (score 0):

When calling from `static` context it should called another `static`.

So just change your funciton to be `static` like:

```
public static int findSmallElement(ArrayList<Integer> num){...}
```

Tip: Try also to see what's happeneds when you're trying to use global static variable from non-static function.